# CopyFileW returns 0 but GetLastError also return 0

Tags: file

Calling CopyFileW from VBA as shown below with a non-existent destination folder gives a value of 0 returned by CopyFileW, but GetLastError also returns 0, indicating a successful operation. How can I get the error code from the failed CopyW operation?

```
Dim Ret As Long

sFrom = "\\?\UNC" & Mid(sFrom, 2)
Ret = CopyFileW(StrPtr(sFrom), StrPtr(sTo), False)

If Ret = 0 Then
        Call LogErrorFilFol(GetFileFromPath(sFrom), GetFolderFromPath(sFrom), _
        "WCopyFile error - " & ErrorMsg(GetLastError), FileID)
End If
```

Comment: GetLastError must be called immediately after CopyFile returns. Not only are you calling other functions in between, the VB runtime is probably also calling other functions as part of the interop layer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `GetLastError` from VBA, use `Err.LastDllError`.

Comment: This is the way to go from within VB6 too.